# How to get the latest data by using the date and time and the same id?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using larave eloquent and I have documents table and remarks table. Remarks table is using the document's id to identify which remarks were made for the document.
In this example I wanted to get the `remarks3` and `remarks4` because it is the latest remarks on each `doc_id`

> documents table:
> id = 1
> id = 2
> remarks table:
> id = 1, doc_id = 1, remarks = remarks1
> id = 2, doc_id = 1, remarks = remarks2
> id = 3, doc_id = 1, remarks = remarks3
> id = 4, doc_id = 2, remarks = remarks4

I use this code for the controller

```
$doc = Documents::all();
$remarks = Remarks::groupBy('doc_id')->get();
```

Comment: laravel have helper `latest()` which u can chaine to `Model::latest()`

Comment: @KamleshPaul I tried but this is the result `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist`

Comment: this seems pretty clear what you are asking for ... did you try adding an 'order by' to this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead use an relationship to have an entry point to only getting the lastest remark. On your `Document.php` model (Please don't do models in plural).

```
public function latestRemark() {
    return $this->hasOne(Remark::class)->latest();
}
```

Now you can simply access your latest remark.

```
$document Document::find($id);

// get remark
$document->latestRemark;
```

Or include it using `with()` for automatic serialization.

```
return Document::with('latestRemark')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know why but it takes all the data not just the latest. If the table with the same `doits_id` appears, it will show all of it.

Comment: can you tell me why it is bad to use plural in the model? I'm a beginner to laravel sorry for asking this question

Comment: Plural models are due to naming conventions. The second question i need more to know what is wrong, how does it show all the data? you can be using the old relationships